# Image Opens as Layer 0 rather than Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Adobe Photoshop CC 2015, I am opening an image (File > Open > Image), and when it opens, it isn't as a locked Background layer. It opens as Layer 0. How can I make my image open as the Background layer?

Comment: Just so you know... You could make that happen, but as Scott points out, it wouldn't make much sense. It would do more hurt than good, if every single transparent image would get it's background taken away.

Comment: Is the image you are opening a PNG with transparency?  That would explain why it's opening as Layer 0.  This is normal. Nothing is wrong.  Photoshop won't open an image with transparency as a "Background" - because that layer generally has no transparency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The image contains transparency.** 
Photoshop honors the transparency and opens it as `Layer 0`.

You can't make Photoshop "open it as a background layer" because then Photoshop would be altering the image as it's opened, and apps just don't do that.

If you want a `Background Layer` you need to flatten the transparency. Simply choose `Flatten Image` From the **Layers Panel Menu**

[image]

Be aware... you'll get a background color which matches the current background color you have set and you'll lose all transparency in the image.

Comment: The answers here are weird because the thing that people say you cannot do, is the default behavior of photoshop when opening most images. I want to know how you got yours to open new images as non-locked-background images. I've probably spent a month of my life duplicating background images into normal layers, then deleting the background layer.

Comment: @John If the image contains **transparency** as in a PNG file, then there will be *no "background layer"*. However, if the image does **not** contain transparency, such as a jpg, then there will *always* be a locked background layer.